API4 - update Participant custom field value?
Have been trying to love the new API4 and it is not easy to.
$results = \Civi\Api4\Participant::update(FALSE)
  ->addValue('CustomFieldGroup.Custom_Field', 4809119164241588000)
  ->setReload(TRUE)
  ->addWhere('id', '=', 5678) //Participant ID
  ->execute();
foreach ($results as $result) {
  // do something
}

Would love to "do something" but the field value doesn't get updated it seems.
What am I missing?

What api action is this? Update?
I suspect it is getting updated, but not returned by "reload" because that probably doesn't include custom fields.
Did you try doing a "get" afterwards to check if the update was successful?
NB: It's not common to "do something" with the results of an update, typically you just update the record and that's it.

@Coleman Thank you! Indeed, it is the "Result" reload issue, the field gets updated fine.

The issue is that ->setReload(TRUE) only returns core fields, not custom fields. If you need to fetch a complete record after updating it, I recommend using the api get action for that.
